# Android Activity Group use

Tags: android, android-studio, activitygroup

how to use Activity Group in android application so that the different activities are able to navigates with the intent  ?? can any one give me better coding example to use activity group in android ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as stated [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) is deprecated. Nowadays Android Developers are using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) with [FragmentManagers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html).

They are pretty simple to use and more flexible to handle. If you want to have downwards compatibility you're able to use the [compability-library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

Comment: I'm researching the SDK and checking requirements for an App, every possible solution that would work involves Activity Group. I'm working with Fragment API at the moment but it doesn't seem to solve the use case - having independent back stacks for app Modules/Sections. How would one implement independent back stacks in a single Activity using fragments ? Can I have more then one FragmentManager in the Activity ?

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you are trying to extend ActivityGroup in your project with specific requirements? If so, the following tutorials with a TabActivity and ActivityGroup may help you.
http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/

here is a another example I found useful:

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html